# Stop a function for some time so that other function can work

Tags: python

For example I have a function named `check_msg()` which calls `check_again()`:

```
def check_again():
    my_msg = message
    if my_msg == '1':
      print('Food will be delivered to you...')
    else:
      print('Food will not be delivered to you!')

def check_msg():
    if message == 'dr strange':
      print('Yes, go further.')
    else:
      print('Not allowed')

while True:
    message = str(input("Type something: "))
    check_msg()
```

Now I want that after I type `dr strange` the `check_msg()` should be stopped until I type something again.

Desired Output:

```
Type something: dr strange
Yes, go further.
Type something: 1
Food will be delivered to you...
```

Any help please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many approaches to do that.

I'll give you a pretty exotic one: let us pretend that different functions are stages of our program. So we call to some stage function and it returns us the next stage function which we'll call again. Do it in the loop until there's no next stage (so the program ends).

```
def check_again():
    number = input("Type number: ")
    if number == '1':
      print('Food will be delivered to you...')
      return None # no next stage
    else:
      print('Food will not be delivered to you!')
      return check_again

def check_name():
    name = input("Type name: ")
    if name == 'dr strange':
      print('Yes, go further.')
      return check_again
    else:
      print('Not allowed')
      return check_name

next_stage_function = check_name # beginning stage
while next_stage_function is not None:
    # execute stage, get next stage
    next_stage_function = next_stage_function()
```